# Printing verbose progress from sed and awk

Tags: sed, awk

The programs `sed` and `awk` usually does their work quietly. Is there any way to get these programs to state what they are doing?

Answer (score 9):

This is based on potong's answer.  The following code replaces 'll' with 'zz', creates a backup file, displays the new text, and writes the change(s) into the file.

```
$ echo hello > test
$ sed -e 's/ll/zz/;w /dev/stdout' -i .backup test
hezzo
$ cat test
hezzo
$ cat test.backup 
hello
```

Comment: In newer sed versions, if the semicolon before the w is omitted, the w becomes an argument to the "s" sed command and only the changes are written to /dev/stdout, which to me is more useful than writing the entire file

Comment: 2020 : g must be added for a global replace ->  sed -i  's/oldtext/newtext/gw /dev/stdout '

Answer (score 6):

On the assumption that you are piping your sed output to a file, you could use the tail command (in another terminal) to constantly look at the end of file; such that you could see the progress.

```
tail -f output_from_sed.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're redirecting the output of `sed` or `awk` to a file (instead of modifying files in-place) you can give `pv` ("pipe viewer") a shot:

```
sed -e '...' input.txt | pv > output.txt
```

You can use `pv -l` to make it report the progress in lines written. The progress status gets printed to `stderr` while the actual data cruises along from `stdin` to `stdout`.

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (for sed):

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/;w /dev/stdout' files*
```

This will print the contents of the file after applying the change.

Comment: For me the -i in the original command doesn't work on OS X.  Is it missing -e?

Comment: Comment by Paul: Worked example using sed for OS X:

`$ echo hello > test
$ sed -e 's/ll/zz/;w /dev/stdout' -i .backup test
hezzo
$ cat test
hezzo
$ cat test.backup 
hello`

Comment: Paul: Mac OS X uses the BSD version of sed, which works differently in some ways to the GNU version commonly found on Linux systems. With BSD sed you must always specify *some* extension for -i, while GNU sed interprets nothing as an empty string. So the BSD sed equivalent of GNU sed's `sed -i` is simply `sed -i ''`.

StuartLC's examples work the same on either version because he isn't editing files in place (ie. he is using non-zero-length extensions, so doesn't run into this small difference).

Answer (score 4):

You can always tell awk to print the input record, i.e.

```
 awk '{ 
       print "#dbg:$0="$0 
       # do more stuff
       print $1
       # or make it conditional
       if ($0 ~ /specialRegEx/){
              print "#dbg:$0="$0 
       }
      }' infile
```

With sed, you use the 'p' cmd to print each line, although, the default is to print each line. Something like

```
 sed 'p
      # also "=" prints line # being processed
      =
      /specialRegEx/{
        s/xxx/yyy/
        p
      }' infile
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux, you can view the progress of process that is processing a large files by looking into `/proc/<pid>/fdinfo`. There is an entry there for each open file descriptor, and if you cat the entries, they show you the read/write position of the file descriptor. So you can see that you are `1123456` bytes into the file.  The path names of open files are in another area: `/proc/<pid>/fd`, represented as symlinks.

Before I look at that, I usually attach an `strace` to the process: `strace -p <pid>`. You can use that to watch what system calls the process is making: file reads and writes, and memory allocations with `brk` or `mmap`.

Comment: For convenience: `ps ax  | grep foo` where `foo` is the name of the program in question can be used to find the process id for use above.

Answer (score 3):

The "right" answer here is

```
pv myfile.txt | sed ...
```

Eduardo Ivanec's answer was close, but by using the pipe viewer (pv) to do the actual piping, you get to know what your progress is in the file (as a percentage, including great stats like M/sec, total data, etc.).

`pv` works like `cat` (read the file and export it directly to `stdout`, or in the case of piping in, it's a bridge between `stdin` and `stdout`).

Importantly, since `pv` is a "transparent pipe process", stdout is occupied with relaying data.  So the progress report is reported through `stderr`.

Comment: Note that this does not work with in-place replacements... (AFAIK)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for but it may help someone else.
FWIW:
`gawk -W dump-variables=/tmp/awk.log`
will dump the variable values at end of the script to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

### `awk` output to `/dev/stderr`

I sometimes process large data files that involve blocks of 4 lines (FASTQ), so I often use `stderr` to output status messages at regular intervals (every 100K lines).  Here's a basic template:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    # Check for any expected input variables

    # Status
    print "[INFO] Initiating processing..." > "/dev/stderr";
}
{
    # Do stuff

    # Status
    if (NR % 400000 == 0) {
        printf("[INFO] %d reads processed\n", NR/4) > "/dev/stderr";
    }
}
END {
    # Final status
    printf("[INFO] %d total reads\n", NR/4) > "/dev/stderr";
}
```